# How to create function(table_name) that returns a set of the table

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a set of tables that share the same fields (some timestamps and users names used for version control). I need to create a function with dynamic sql that uses a table_name and a timestamp as arguments and returns a set of the same table.

The query I need is a bit more complicated, but for my question the following example should be enough.

This is how I'm trying to create the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "vsr_versioning_at_time"(_t regclass
                                                  , _d timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS SETOF _t AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT ON (gid) * 
        FROM '|| _t || 
        'WHERE vrs_start_time <= '|| _d ||
        'ORDER BY gid, vrs_start_time DESC';
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The creation of this function fails since `_t` is not recognized by the `RETURN SETOF _t`.

Comment: Exact error message? And what is `_t`? Is there actually a type or table named `_t` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter name (`_t`) as return type.
Use [**polymorphic types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vsr_versioning_at_time(_t anyelement, _d timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
       SELECT DISTINCT ON (gid) * 
       FROM   %s
       WHERE  vrs_start_time <= $1
       ORDER  BY gid, vrs_start_time DESC'
     , pg_typeof(_t)
     )
   USING _d;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And use [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to actually *return* the results.
Call (important!):

```
SELECT * FROM vsr_versioning_at_time(NULL::mytable, '2014-04-18 12:00');
```

A lot more details in this related answer on SO (last chapter):
[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much. Your answers are always both useful as educative.